# Templates .dwt in Dreamweaver

Tags: templates, dreamweaver, dwt

I edited my site with FrontPage, there I created some template pages .dwt in the root of the each language `/en/master.dwt` `/fr/master.dwt` and so one.

Now, when passed the site under Adobe Dreamweaver, it seems do not "recognize" them.

I understood that Dreamweaver puts all templates in a folder `Templates`, but... I don't want it. It broke all my relative paths!

Is it a way to tell Dreamweaver do use my templates there where they are?

Comment: Not that I know of, as far as I know it only recognizes the Templates folder for templates

Comment: @Anthony: maybe then at last a Template folder for each language?...

Comment: I think Dreamweaver specifies a certain path, I believe that being *yourSiteFolder\Templates* so I don't think *yourSiteFolder\fr\Templates* would work, but *yourSiteFolder\Templates\fr* might

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the .dwt file is moved from the Templates folder, or if the Templates folder is moved or renamed, the link will be broken. It is very important to keep the .dwt file in the Templates folder where Dreamweaver creates it.

Taken from [**Understanding paths in Dreamweaver templates**](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/138/tn_13842.html)

I suggest you create each language as an independent folder inside of your Templates folder.

So `/fr/master.dwt` becomes `Templates/fr/master.dwt`

In the end, it makes sense to have your templates exist inside of a templates folder organized by language.